# How to init UIViewController with UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a WebViewController that inherits from UIViewController and also use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Well so good so far, but when I switch to the WebViewController, then is starts in Portrait mode. Only when I turn the iPhone, it starts rotating.

Now any idea how to start in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this tutorial](http://dejoware.com/tutorials/files/iphone_programming_landscape_view_tutorial.php) - it should solve your problem.

Basically, you have to add a key `UIInterfaceOrientation` with value `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` in your Info.plist file.